redis not connecting from docker
I have an app running in docker and also have redis as a service. Redis is building successfully and i can see the service running in same container but the app is unable to connect it.
Docker service running
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                           PORTS                                       NAMES
48007b9bc91f   redis:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 seconds ago   Up 1 second (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   symfony_redis

redis connection error from symfony application using snc-redis package
Connection refused [tcp://0.0.0.0:6379]

docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    build:
      context: .docker/redis
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: redis:7.2.4
    container_name: symfony_redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - app-network

  api:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: tazman-backend/symfony/.docker/api/Dockerfile
    container_name: symfony_api
    volumes:
      - ../../components:/var/www/html/components:rw,cached
      - ../:/var/www/html/backend:rw,cached
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      APP_ENV: dev
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  redis-data:

networks:    # Define the network
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


You say the app is also running in Docker; how did you start the two containers?  It looks like your application is trying to connect to 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces") as the Redis location and that doesn't necessarily make sense.

docker compose up --build -d, i started the redis service alone and it was starting perfectly, but when i build with app, the app is unable to connect to it.

@Mike i just updated the question with docker-compose.yaml file. I have added depends_on section properly

Where do you set the location of the Redis server in your application configuration?

@David Maze in my .env file as REDIS_URL="redis://redis:6379"

@AhmedAli Is the container symfony_api also located in the app-network network? If so, the connection URL would be REDIS_URL="redis://symfony_redis:6379.

@Bademeister i have tried symfony_redis, redis, localhost, 0.0.0.0 but none of them worked.

redis and api containers should utilize the same network, you have specified custom network for redis (it would depend on your requirements/necessities, but in most common cases you can run without specifying any custom network, it would use your default network)
networks:
  - app-network

so you need either to remove custom network from your redis container, or add the same networks part to your api container's description

both services using the same network, i have updated my question
